# Children's book about merpeople

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

I have a vague memory of a book where the protagonist is a human child but transforms into a mer-person and has guided adventures with a group of mer. I recall that the merfolk come in a large variety of sizes. For some reason i remember that a sewer drain is a part of the beginning.

Comment: In roughly which year did you read this book, and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall any details about the cover, and was the child a boy or a girl?

Comment: I read it in the 70s.  I don't recall the cover at all.  Don't recall the gender either

Comment: If it predates the 70s I'd have guessed at The Water-Babies, but I don't think any sewers feature in that.

Comment: Are you thinking of the 1870s?

Comment: I was born in 1969 so it couldn't have been the 1870s.  It wasn't a fairy tale children's book at all. It was more like a tween fictional book